# Get all running applications programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to know programmatically how many applications are running in background in Windows Phone 8. Are there any API or methods available ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to know that.

all applications are in sandbox and can't access to informations like that